# API to receive JSON request body and forward to another API - Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

An orchestration API is supposed to take a JSON request body and forward to another API. What features of Springboot allow for forwarding a request to another endpoint? In the below code, how can I forward the request body through the redirect?

```
 @PostMapping("/redirect")
    public RedirectView getRedirection(@RequestBody List<Request> request){
     return new RedirectView("other api url");
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot. Forward on RestController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73108875/spring-boot-forward-on-restcontroller)

Comment: Should you redirect to an internal API(from Controller A to Controller B) or external redirect ?

Comment: It will be external

Comment: just have a look at [spring-cloud-feign](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-feign)